# Mutate when function output has data in two columns (geosphere)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, geosphere

I have animal survey data from transects. Transects are divided into sections. There are lat/lon data for the start/endpoints of some sections but not others, and I want to calculate the start/endpoints for sections where these values are missing. Missing start/endpoints should be calculated using the section bearing (degrees), section length (m).

Example data:

| Section | StartLon | StartLat | EndLon | EndLat | Bearing | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -132.4053 | 53.00704 | -132.4053 | 53.00714 | 360 | 5 |
| 2 | -132.4053 | 53.00714 | NA | NA | 360 | 10 |

I'm trying to use destPoint (geosphere) to calculate the missing start/endpoints (NAs). The output of destPoint looks like:

```
        lon       lat
[1,] -132.4053 53.00701
```

My code:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(EndLon = if_else(is.na(EndLon), destPoint(c(StartLon, StartLat), Bearing, Length), EndLon))

data %>% 
  mutate(EndLat = if_else(is.na(EndLat), destPoint(c(StartLon, StartLat), Bearing, Length), EndLat))
```

My code gives this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `test`.
x Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
i Input `test` is `if_else(...)`
```

I think the error is because the output of destPoint is two values (lon and lat), and the mutated column can only hold one value. Maybe there's a way to use select() so that only lon or lat goes into the mutated column?

Hoping for a dplyr solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
data %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(EndLon = if(is.na(EndLon)) 
       destPoint(c(StartLon, StartLat), Bearing, Length)[, 'lon'] else EndLon) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#  Section StartLon StartLat EndLon EndLat Bearing Length
#    <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>  <int>
#1       1    -132.     53.0  -132.   53.0     360      5
#2       2    -132.     53.0  -132.   NA       360     10
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Section = 1:2, StartLon = c(-132.4053, -132.4053
), StartLat = c(53.00704, 53.00714), EndLon = c(-132.4053, NA
), EndLat = c(53.00714, NA), Bearing = c(360L, 360L), Length = c(5L, 
10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

---

The issue would be that `c(StartLon, StartLat)` would concatenate the whole column values from both of those column, and thereby the `length` of one of the arguments for `if_else` becomes different in `length` than the rest.  If we do the `rowwise`, it is grouped by `row` and we can use `if/else` (which requires a input logical expression of `length` 1)